# In CloudTrail (API) how can I list event names only

Tags: aws-cli

I'm trying to create some metrics graphs to track our API calls and I want to start breaking down by event names. Looking through the web interface and cli, I have to scroll through a lot of data to see different types of events.

I just want the list of all Event names.

Thank you

Devon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to see a list of event names, you can use the `--query` option to filter the data returned by the service.  For example:

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --query Events[].EventName
[
    "ConsoleLogin", 
   "DescribeAccountLimits", 
    "ConsoleLogin",
   ...
]
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: One more question. How would I get all of the events with usernames for a full day or time range?

Answer (score 3):

You can also get a fairly comprehensive list of [CloudTrail Events here](https://www.gorillastack.com/news/cloudtrail-event-names/) so you know what you're looking for.